# Confusion with UIScrollView and setContentSize

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, xcode4.2

In Xcode 3, I followed a tutorial on UIScrollView that told me to set the size of my View to be 320x650, and then drag a ScrollView on top of that View.  After adding:

```
[scrollView isScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGMakeSize(320, 650)];
```

in the viewDidLoad, and after attaching all the outlets properly, everything worked, I was able to see the scroll bars when I tried moving the screen up and down.

However, when I tried the same tutorial in Xcode 4.2, it didn't work, ie. I couldn't scroll the view.  It appears that I need to set the content size to be larger than the size of the ScrollView.

Is this something that changed in XCode 4.2, or was the original tutorial wrong?

Should the size of the scrollView always be 320x480?  I no longer understand the semantics of what this all means now, ie. why I need to setContentSize of the scrollView, but also set the size of the scrollView in Interface Builder.  When I initially drag the scrollView on top of a View, it comes out the same size as the View.  Is this wrong?

Comment: I'm semi-new to iOS development and I've had to extensively use the UIScrollView for my application.  What I have discovered is that the ScrollView doesn't do anything until it actually needs to start scrolling something on the screen.  My guess is that back when your tutorial was written, the view would still respond to the panning gesture and move the screen and snap back once the user's finger was removed from the screen.  This behavior was probably moved with a framework upgrade because it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a UIScrollView, the contentSize is generally going to be larger than the frame size of the UIScrollView.  The point of setting contentSize is to tell UIScrollView how large its scrollable area is.  When the user drags the content around, the UIScrollView will know how far it can drag it left or right or up or down.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So let's say my View is (320,700).  The ScrollView that I dragged onto the View is then also (320,700).  In order for my ScrollView to scroll, what should I setContentSize, should it be (320,750)?

Comment: You should drag the UIView onto the UIScrollView.  If you then set the contentSize to 320 x 750 you can then drag the view up and down.